# How do I let spring set certain variables for all controllers/actions

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine, annotations, tiles

I use a configuration of google app engine, spring and tiles where each controller actions results in some set of nested (tiles) jsp's to be rendered. Some of the elements of the jsp are to be calculated/set for (almost) each controller, for example the login/logout link somewhere on a page:

```jsp
<%
com.google.appengine.api.users.UserService userService =
  com.google.appengine.api.users.UserServiceFactory.getUserService();
com.google.appengine.api.users.User user = userService.getCurrentUser();
if (user != null) {%>
  <li class="active"><a href="#feeds">Feeds</a></li>
  <li class="active"><a href="<%=userService.createLogoutURL("")%>">Logout</a></li>
<%} else {%>
  <li class="active"><a href="<%=userService.createLoginURL("")%>">Login</a></li>
<%}%>
```

Of course, this is possible and I could also make static-classes which can simplify such code. Yet this is not something I like to have in my jsp, moreover it is (possibly) impossible in templating engines like thymeleaf do execute code like that. Therefore, how do I do something like this:

```jsp
@RequestMapping("/foo")
public class FooController {
    @RequestMapping(value="/{bar}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getMovie(@PathVariable String bar, ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("bar", bar);
        model.addAttribute("message", "message");
        UserService userService = UserServiceFactory.getUserService();
                    User user = userService.getCurrentUser();
        model.addAttribute("isLoggedIn", user==null);

        return "somepage";

    }
}
```

So summarized: How do I prevent that the isLoggedIn-code is duplicated everywhere, preferably a solution different than needing to call some "initUserModel(model)" method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tiles knows the concept of a [ViewPreparer](http://tiles.apache.org/2.2/framework/tutorial/advanced/preparer.html). ViewPreparer are executed before the definition is rendered and is a good place to set attributes that are common for your Tiles views. Those attributes can be request attributes (as shown below) or tiles attributes as shown in the example on the mentioned [ViewPreparer tutorial page](http://tiles.apache.org/2.2/framework/tutorial/advanced/preparer.html).

A ViewPreparer is implemented as a "normal" spring service:

```
@Component
public class YourViewPreparer implements ViewPreparer {
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Override
    public void execute(TilesRequestContext tilesContext, AttributeContext attributeContext) {
        // Some magic here to get the HttpRequest...
        Object[] requestObjects = tilesContext.getRequestObjects();
        if (requestObjects.length == 2) {
            HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) requestObjects[0];
            User user = userService.getCurrentUser();
            request.setAttribute("isLoggedIn", user != null);
        }
    }
}
```

Then configure your TilesConfigurer by setting the preparerFactoryClass property to pick up any ViewPreparer beans like this:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer" id="tilesConfigurer">
    <property name="definitions">
        ...
    </property>
    <property name="preparerFactoryClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.SimpleSpringPreparerFactory" />
</bean>
```

And define the preparer in your view declaration. You can extend all your views from a base view so that the preparer declaration has to be done only once.

```
<definition name="main" preparer="com.example.YourViewPreparer">
    ...
</definition>

<definition name="myView" extends="main">
    ...
</definition>
```

Alternatively you could also implement your own [HandlerInterceptor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html) if you have other views than Tiles views.

Comment: Why do you check "(requestObjects.length == 2)" ?

Comment: Good question. Maybe there is some less obscure way to determine what kind of Object array the call to getRequestObjects() returns... There are two implementations of TilesRequestContext: ServletTilesRequestContext and JspTilesRequestContext (where the first is is the one we're after). When looking at the implementations, ServletTilesRequestContext returns an Object[] with two elements, where JspTilesRequestContext returns an Object[] with just one element.

Maybe it would be more clear to test the 0th element of the returned array like `if (requestObjects[0]instanceof HttpServletRequest) {}`

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  When using `org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.SimpleSpringPreparerFactory` you don't need to (and shouldn't) annotate `YourViewPreparer` with `@Component`. To do so leads to an instance of  `YourViewPreparer` in the app context that never gets used - as `SimpleSpringPreparerFactory` creates its own on demand.

Alternatively, use `org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.SpringBeanPreparerFactory` which does look up the preparer instance from the app context by name.

Comment: This code doesn't work in Tiles 3.In ViewPreparer class  `execute(TilesRequestContext tilesContext, AttributeContext attributeContext)`  was changed to `ViewPreparer. execute(org.apache.tiles.request.Request tilesContext, AttributeContext attributeContext)`. **Request** class doesn't have getRequestObjects() method.